# xstream marshal to XML - add attribute based on number of child nodes

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I'm pretty new to xstream. 
I'm working on a model class that looks like the following:

```
@XStreamAlias("MyRootClass")
public class MyRootClass {

// A bunch of other classes as child nodes

    @XStreamAlias("MyClassList")
    private List<MyClass> foo;
}
```

Now, is there a way for me to produce the following XML when marshalling, without modifying the class?

```
<MyRootClass>
    <!-- a bunch of other class nodes -->
    <MyClassList COUNT="3">
        <MyClass>MyClass 1</MyClass>
        <MyClass>MyClass 2</MyClass>
        <MyClass>MyClass 3</MyClass>
    </MyClassList>
</MyRootClass>
```

The main issue is how to add the attribute "COUNT" to the list of MyClass gracefully. It will always show the number of MyClass inside MyClassList.

I am not allowed to modify the model class. However, I can implement my own converter to achieve the above.

The question is: what's the best way to do it? 
There are lots of other (complex) classes within MyRootClass, and they've all been aliased & annotated. So, creating a 'marshal' method from scratch might be overkill?

Answer (score 0):

welp, I figured it out. 
Not sure if this is the "best" way to do it, but it works.

the key is using converters and nested converters.
this is what I ended up doing:

```
public class MyRootClassConverter implements Converter {
    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return type.equals(MyRootClassConverter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        MyRootClass rootClass= (MyRootClass) source;

        // as necessary
        writer.startNode("Other Class1");
        writer.setValue("Other Class Value");
        writer.endNode();

        if (rootClass.getMyClassList() != null || !rootClass.getMyClassList().isEmpty()) {
            writer.startNode("MyClassList");
            writer.addAttribute("COUNT", String.valueOf(rootClass.getMyClassList().size()));
            for (MyClass child : rootClass.getMyClassList()) {
                writer.startNode("MyClass");
                context.convertAnother(child); // this is where the nesting happens
                writer.endNode();
            }
            writer.endNode(); 
        }
    }
}
```